# How can I remove excess fat/oil from my slow cooker dish?

Tags: oil

when we are cooking something, we don’t know how much oil we need, so sometimes we add too much oil, which affects the taste of the dish.

What can I do when this happened? How can I remove the excess oil?

Comment: We do not accept questions about health (apart from food safety aspects), so I removed the part. Let me remind you that the checking [ask] before posting a question is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depend on the dish that you are making.There are lots of method to remove extra oil from the cooked dish .one and the easiest way is that if you are making a vegetable or fried dish you can remove extra oil by just putting all the dish on Slotted spoon.in this way all extra oil can be remove without destroying the taste of dish.but if you are making any liquid dish you can remove extra oil by using ice or you can cool the dish and the whole oil appear in a layer and you can easily remove that layer of oil.

Answer (score 1):

Oil typically floats to the top in most dishes. In that case it is a simple matter of using a ladle to skim excess oil from the dish. This won't work in all cases because emulsifiers and other agents will cause oils to dissolve in the dish.